# Opencart module installation error

Tags: module, installation, opencart

I've installed an extension via opencart admin panel Extensions -> Extension Installer and success message says extension successfully installed. 
Added module properly shows in modification section. After refreshing modification then in the module section Currently installed module is not showing.
So i've manually installed the plugin. then the module is showing in the modules list. But while applying the modification file, 
It shows Modification 'filename' is using the same ID code as the one you are trying to upload! or some times it shows this file could not be applied.
How can i solve the issue.

i'm using opencart version Version 2.0.3.0

Answer (score 0):

What extension is this?

Usually the first thing to do is contact the extension developer via the OpenCart Support system:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=support/contact